# Django - 2 Foreign Key fields in one model (limit choices)

Tags: django

I am trying to add simple option to my admin panel. I have category, subcategory and site models. For example:
Computers (category)
   - PC (subcategory)
   - Notebooks (subcategory)
Health (category)
   - Diet (subcategory) 
   - Fitness (subcategory)
Subcategory is within category. When I am adding site in my admin panel I have list of all categories and subcategories. When I choose category (Computers) in my Subcategory field I have: PC, Notebooks, Diet, Fitness (all subcategories). I don't have any idea how can I filter this only to PC and Notebooks. Any suggestions?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True,
                        verbose_name='Nazwa kategorii')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category_images',
                          verbose_name="Image",
                          blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='Description',
                               verbose_name="Category description")

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def image_thumb(self):
    if self.image:
        return '<img src="/media/%s" width="40" height="40" />' % (self.image)
    else:
        return('')
image_thumb.short_description = 'Thumb'
image_thumb.allow_tags = True

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Category',
        related_name='subcategory',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Subcategories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Site(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    # sub = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=category)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('SubCategory', related_name='subcategory')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: Try [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)

Comment: Great:) It works. Thank you.